# Python Script to Pyspark Script

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am unable to convert this data into `pyspark script`.

```
    data = [(1, 'N'),
            (2, 'N'),
            (3, 'N'),
            (4, 'Y'),
            (5, 'Y'),
            (6, 'N'),
            (7, 'N'),
            (8, 'Y'),
            (9, 'Y'),
            (10, 'N')]
    modified_data = []
    new_col = 0  # Initialize new_col
    for id_, flag in data:
        if flag == 'N':
            new_col = id_ - 1
        modified_data.append((id_, flag, new_col))
    print(modified_data)
```

The result should be:

```
[(1, 'N', 0), (2, 'N', 1), (3, 'N', 2), (4, 'Y', 2), (5, 'Y', 2), (6, 'N', 5), (7, 'N', 6), (8, 'Y', 6), (9, 'Y', 6), (10, 'N', 9)]
```

Here data is dataframe. Need to add `new_col` into it with the result value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

data = [
    (1, 'N'),
    (2, 'N'),
    (3, 'N'),
    (4, 'Y'),
    (5, 'Y'),
    (6, 'N'),
    (7, 'N'),
    (8, 'Y'),
    (9, 'Y'),
    (10, 'N')
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'flag'])
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('new_col', f.when(f.col('flag') == 'N', f.col('id') - 1))
    .withColumn('new_col', f.when(f.col('new_col').isNull(), f.last(f.col('new_col'), True).over(Window.orderBy('id'))).otherwise(f.col('new_col')))
)

df.show()
```

And the output is:

```
+---+----+-------+                                                              
| id|flag|new_col|
+---+----+-------+
|  1|   N|      0|
|  2|   N|      1|
|  3|   N|      2|
|  4|   Y|      2|
|  5|   Y|      2|
|  6|   N|      5|
|  7|   N|      6|
|  8|   Y|      6|
|  9|   Y|      6|
| 10|   N|      9|
+---+----+-------+
```